# How to parse json in python

Tags: python, json

i want to get token through the result of REST API and it has done and success. the result of REST API shown below following `print(result)` of python

```
'{"UserId":"202","UserName":"xxx","UserMail":"yyy","Token":"abcdfghoijkalt"}'
```

do you know how to get "Token" as variable?, so i can get to next step. thank you

Comment: Do you mean something other than `import json` / `dct = json.loads( result )`?  Python has a built-in `json` module.

Comment: Have a read of this: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp
Note: This was the first google result from the search: `python string to json`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `json.loads`

```py
import json

jObject = json.loads('{"UserId":"202","UserName":"xxx","UserMail":"yyy","Token":"abcdfghoijkalt"}')
# This should give you the value you are looking for:
token = jObject["Token"]
print(token)
```

Comment: it totally works. thank you, but i have new issue with same json format as same as above, that ther error says: 'dict' object has no attribute 'loads'

Comment: Have you assigned a variable named "json"?

Answer (score 0):

I have written a short write util function (below) which I include in every project I work on. So if your target file has a .json extension, it automatically format it into json.

eg. `write(result, "dst_dir/dst_file.json")`

```
import json
def write(content, file, **kwargs):
    if not isinstance(file, str):
        file = str(file)

    if file.endswith('.json'):
        with open(file, 'w') as f:
            json.dump(content, f, indent=2, **kwargs)
    else:
        with open(file,'w') as f:
            f.write(content, **kwargs)

write(result, "dst_dir/dst_file.json") # To run it with your result
```